# Como melhorar o desempenho do SQL com cláusula IN?

Tags: sql, desempenho

Tenho esse SQL aqui:

```
SELECT id, nome, url FROM categorias WHERE status = 1 AND id_ls IN 
(SELECT id_categoria FROM cliente_categorias) GROUP BY url
```

O que ele faz é buscar **somente categorias que tenham clientes atribuídos a elas.**

Minha tabela categorias tem 1.477 registros e cliente_categorias 23.616:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona. O problema é que o carregamento está muuuuito lento. A consulta demora cerca de 17 segundos. Tem alguma forma de eu melhorar?

Comment: Qual é a quantidade de registros? Será que cliente_categorias precise de um distinct ? Coloque o diagrama dessas duas tabelas!

Comment: Você está utilizando [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) ou [cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) ?

Comment: Não entendi o porquê do `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Oi virgilio! Obrigada por contribuir, editei a pergunta com mais infos :)

Comment: Tente usar EXISTS(select top 1 1 from ... ) ao inves de IN

Comment: @VictorStafusa preciso agrupar uns resultados por causa de uma questão externa ao projeto. esse banco puxa dados de um banco offline que tem alguns problemas de estrutura. Mas removendo o group by em nada altera o carregamento.

Comment: Se esse `GROUP BY` não mudar em nada o resultado, recomendo tirar. Vejo ele como algo que pode inibir otimizações que o banco de dados faria se você tentar alguma coisa que está nas respostas abaixo.

Comment: Quanto tempo deu minha query? :-P

Comment: Qual a diferença entre as coluna `id` e `id_ls` na tabela `categorias`? Na tabela `categorias` a chave primária é a coluna `id`, mas no código que postou o join é estabelecido com a coluna `id_ls`. Estranhei isto.

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? (mariaDB, SQL Server, Oracle Database etc)

Comment: Um cliente pode estar várias vezes na mesma categoria?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente isso:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.nome, c.url
FROM categorias c
INNER JOIN cliente_categorias d ON d.id_categoria = c.id_ls
WHERE c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.url
```

Tente também criar um índice para deixar esse tipo de consulta mais rápida:

```
ALTER TABLE cliente_categorias ADD INDEX idx_categoria_categorias_cliente (id_categoria);
```

Comment: Oi Victor :) obrigada por contribuir. O carregamento melhor, mas ainda é lento (9 seg). Vou editar a pergunta para adicionar mais informações.

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia Resposta editada. Veja o que acontece agora.

Comment: Por que o indice no id_cliente? não seria no id_categoria?

Comment: @Zorkind Oops. Realmente, você está correto. Foi um descuido. Obrigado por avisar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sem problemas :-)

Answer (score 3):

Faz a prova utilize `distinct`, exemplo:

```
SELECT id, nome, url FROM categorias WHERE status = 1 AND id_ls IN 
(SELECT distinct id_categoria FROM cliente_categorias) GROUP BY url
```

Comment: Oi Virgilio, obrigada por contribuir mas o tempo de carregamento não altera. Segue o mesmo.

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia tem os indices criados na tabela nos campos id_categoria da tabela cliente_categorias?

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia pode ser também o GROUP BY url, esse campo url é de qual tamanho, tem indice nele!, é necessário?

Answer (score 3):

Tente com `EXISTS`

```
SELECT id, nome, url FROM categorias WHERE status = 1 
AND EXISTS(select top 1 1 FROM cliente_categorias where id_categoria = id_ls) GROUP BY url
```

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver com ajuda de todos. De fato a criação de índices melhorou o carregamento para 4 segundos (ainda um pouco lento) mas acredito que isso aconteça pela quantidade de registros.

Algumas observações de acordo com o que todo mundo postou aí:

- O group by é realmente necessário.
- O distinct não mudou em nada o carregamento.
- O exists deixou ainda mais lento.

A query permaneceu igual, apenas adicionei os índices nas tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: Pode ser que você tenha inserts mais lentos, mas não acho que deva impactar muito, fico feliz que tenha resolvido, acredito que a resposta que mereça ser dada como certa é a do Victor :-)